# React Native - Setting TextInput cursor position

Tags: android, ios, react-native

In my React Native app, I am trying to set the cursor position of a `TextInput` to a particular position (eg. to the 5th character) but am have trouble doing so as the documentation is lacking a little. I suspect it has something to do with the 'setSelection' property of `TextInput` but I cannot seem to find out what to do.

Has anyone successfully done so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

As @this.lau_ says there is a controlled property called `selection` which accepts an object with keys start and end.

Example:

```
class ControlledSelectionInput extends Component {
    state = {
        selection: {
            start: 0,
            end: 0
        }
    }

    // selection is an object: { start:number, end:number }
    handleSelectionChange = ({ nativeEvent: { selection } }) => this.setState({ selection })

    render() {
        const { selection } = this.state;

        return <TextInput selection={selection} onSelectionChange={this.handleSelectionChange} />
    }
}
```

You can also programmatically set the selection by getting a ref to the component and using `setNativeProps` like this:

```
this.inputRef.setNativeProps({ selection:{ start:1, end:1 } })
```

Example:

```
class SetNativePropsSelectionInput extends Component {
    inputRef = null

    render() {
        const { selection } = this.state;

        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput ref={this.refInput} />
                <Button title="Move selection to start" onPress={this.handleMoveSelectionPress} />
            </View>
    }

    refInput = el => this.inputRef = el

    handleMoveSelectionPress = () => this.input.setNativeProps({
        selection: {
            start: 0,
            end: 0
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: We aware that in the second solution (using nativeProps) the focus will stay at the given nativeProps, so go for solution 1 which change the selection when user type.

Comment: @HugoGresse sorry I don't understand. Do you mean that, while focus is not inside the TextInput, changing selection with nativeProps will move focus into the TextInput? And using `selection` will prevent focus from moving inside?

Comment: My bad for not being clear, I mean using both methods, the selection needs to be updated when user add text to the input otherweise the selection will stay at its current position. If you set the selection to start: text.length, end: text.length, the user input will be added before the current selection.

Comment: `setNativeProps` seems to work well on both iOS and Android. The only issue is that it results in the selection being permanent. Following up the `setNativeProps` with `setTimeout(() => this.inputRef.setNativeProps({ selection: null }), 0)` seems so far to work for switching the selection back to being uncontrolled after selecting. Pretty hacky though, so I'm thinking using the `selection` prop might end up being better, even though the API is not as nice for declaratively selecting.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 9):

There is now a [selection](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#selection) property on `TextInput` which can be used to set the selection or the caret/cursor position.

Comment: Thanks for this! It led me to find what I needed. Programmatic setting. Solution with examples for both ways shared here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49112887/1828637

Answer (score 2):

I think I wanted something similar. I wanted to reset the start to 0 when the input was active but still allow the user to move the cursor. I have a state variable that tracks when an input is active ("isActive"), so I did this:

```
<TextInput selection={this.state.isActive ? undefined : { start: 0 }} />
```

I used `undefined` because it was the only 'default' value I could find with the selection prop.

Comment: Welcome to this site! Keep going! You are the future of this site

Answer (score 0):

I just know the native way:

```
public static void adjustCursor(EditText dgInput) {
    CharSequence text = dgInput.getText();
    if (text instanceof Spannable && text.length() > 0) {
        Spannable spanText = (Spannable) text;
        Selection.setSelection(spanText, text.length());
    }
}
```

Maybe you can find same method in React Native.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `setSelection` property in the documentation https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html, nor do I believe this is supported in core.

If you're doing this in Android, I suggest you take Tiny's code and build your own native component. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#content

Of course, you could do the same in iOS if you have the skills...
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#content

Comment: My mistake, I meant 'selectionState' property.

Comment: Ah, no... that's to select a range of text. It doesn't appear to support cursor placement. See for yourself... [Libraries/Components/TextInput.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/f407211131b3fdae77e93068407b2e8471f332d9/Libraries/Components/TextInput/TextInput.js#L267) which references [DocumentSelectionState.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/62e8ddc20561a39c3c839ab9f83c95493df117c0/Libraries/vendor/document/selection/DocumentSelectionState.js)

Answer (score 0):

**It seems like that selection only works when your Text Input is in focus**

You can do the following things to make it work

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component{
      constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
       text:'Hello World',
       selection: {
        start: 0,
        end: 0
       }
  };

this.inputRefs = {};
}

   setSelection = () => {
      this.setState({ select: { start: 1, end: 1 } });
      };

    changeText = (val) => {
     this.inputRefs.input.focus();
    }

    render(){
       return(
          <TextInput 
            onFocus={this.setSelection}
            selection={this.state.setSelection} 
            onChangeText={val => {this.changeText(val)}} 
            value={this.state.text}
             refName={ref => {
             this.inputRefs.input = ref;
             }}
            />
       )
    }
}
```

The idea is whenever your TextInput calls the onChangeText call-back put the focus on your TextInput through refs, as your component is responding to onFocus call back we will set the selection on that call back

Comment: how is it possible ? There is no item such setSelection in the states :(
and also select