# How to change cursor position on TextInput? (react-native)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I can get cursor position using

```
onSelectionChange={(event) => console.log(event.nativeEvent.selection)}
```

But how to change it?

Comment: Solution found - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49112887/1828637

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native - Setting TextInput cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33686748/react-native-setting-textinput-cursor-position)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[react-native-textinput-utils](https://github.com/DickyT/react-native-textinput-utils)  <- This lib can help u.

Till now there's no api for us to change it.

You could subscribe [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2478) for furture improvement.

Comment: No need for this lib, its built into RN - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49112887/1828637

Answer (score 0):

some have used the TextInput as TouchableHighlight, I want to press the TextInput and then it is sent to another window with the `Actions.Places ({type: 'replace'});` Then that data obtained through google places are shown in my TextInput. [Something like this catch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlpyb.png)