# How to change cursor position when press in TextInput

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, text

For example i have a TextInput like this

```
<ScrollView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Input"
        style={{fontSize: 50}}
        value={'Sample text'}
      />
</ScrollView>
```

So normally, when we click on the TextInput, it will automatic show caret at the end of text ( **on android** ), no matter where we click, at the first time, it will have the caret at the end, like this

[image]

BUT HOW can we set the caret in where we click, for example when we click the "m" letter, it will have caret after the "m", like this

[image]

Problem is, as i said, on android we always have the the caret at the end first, then if we click other, the caret will more to that, like this

[image]

I mean, it not a problem when text is short, but imagine, the text will like this

[image]

And we want to edit some text that already exist, so it scroll all the way down to the bottom (because the bottom contain the lastest text)

So my question is

**HOW CAN WE SET THE CARET ON WHERE WE TOUCH (OR CLICK), NOT FROM LASTEST WORD IN TEXTINPUT?**

Comment: Does that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33686748/react-native-setting-textinput-cursor-position answer your question?

Comment: @DaviCheliMiquelim it very like a solution but it not, i want the caret right after i click , and i confirm it a bug with react-native-cli on android, the behavior not on ios and expo

Comment: You should open an issue on their GitHub repository if you are sure it is a bug. Repo link: https://github.com/facebook/react-native

Answer (score 0):

You need to request focus to this TextInput.

```
<TextInput
    placeholder="Input"
    autofocus={true}
    style={{fontSize: 50}}
    value={'Sample text'}
  />
```

Or if it will not be working, write this please
https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal/issues/516

Comment: It not solve my question, it just focus on last text again